# Multiple db users for multiple db connections

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-connection

I'm using 2 different databases on my CI app.

I created 2 users on mysql, and granted user1 to db1 all privileges, then user2 to db2 all privileges with SQLpro client.

The database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;   

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '***1';
$db['default']['password'] = '***1';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci_users';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['keys']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['keys']['username'] = '***2';
$db['keys']['password'] = '***2';
$db['keys']['database'] = 'ci_keys';
$db['keys']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['keys']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['keys']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['keys']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['keys']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['keys']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['keys']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['keys']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
$db['keys']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['keys']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['keys']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

The models:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_Users extends CI_Model {
    function Model_Users()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('default',true);
    }
etc...


<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_Keys extends CI_Model {
    function Model_Keys()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('keys',true);
    }
etc...
```

So when using both models in same controller/method the model_users works great but model_keys returns an error, because it seems to load anyway the model_users db1 instead ofl oading db2:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/application/models/model_keys.php:2)
>   Filename: core/Common.php
>   Line Number: 442
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1146
>   Table 'ci_users.ci_keys' doesn't exist //this should be ci_keys.ci_keys

Does anyone has idea?

I edited code in model_keys:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_Keys extends CI_Model {

    function Model_Keys()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db_keys = $this->load->database('keys',true);
    }
```

Now db works but I receive session error on model:

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/application/models/model_keys.php:2)

In controller i'm doing this:

```
$this->load->model('model_users');
$this->model_users->insert(bla bla);

$this->load->model('model_keys');
$this->model_keys->insert(bla bla);

$this->session->set_userdata(array(bl bla);

redirect(some url);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below line is problem

```
$this->load->database('keys',true);
```

If you pass second argument TRUE, then it will return database object and it will not work with ActiveRecord.

Here is example

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);

//Then you can't below function
$this->db->query();

You will instead use:

$DB1->query();
```

Comment: thx, i edited question cause i'm receiving error with session it's strange

Comment: error says header output start in model_keys.php before redirection. try to put ob_start() before redirect(some url);

Comment: tryed but it doesn't produces nothing and doesn't fix nothing :P

Comment: what is on line 2 in model_keys.php ?

Comment: <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Comment: tryed removing but it's the same :/

Comment: i removed the first file line which was empty before <?php etc.. now it works :/

Comment: Yes.. because somewhere output already started to sent to browser.